# How to Solve Equations in iOS

Tags: ios, algebra, quadratic

Is there api's or tools that I can use do something in Xcode like

```
SOLVE(2x = x +7);
```

and I get x = 7?

Also more complication stuffs like

```
SOLVE(x^2= +6x -8);
```

and get x = 2 or x = 4

So basically you give an equation with one variable, and it returns the value of that variable.

I have really complicated quadratic equation that needs to be solved.

I am finding intersection of 3 spheres using iBeacons, and I have a complicated equation that needs to be solved. It is too long, complicated to do it myself and create the formula. I need this functionality to make my app work well. But I don't think it exists from my research. So I am asking for your help.

UPDATE: it is possible to do this in Python, but iOS does not include the Python framework. Using python to use sympy in iOS is not feasible. (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

UPDATE: There is no easy answer. I had to solve equation by myself. Creating formulas for solving equations is easy with programming cuz you can always create new variables to replace many constants together and go step by step.

Comment: what why would you -1 this?? Explain?

Comment: can you use python? Then sympy will do the job

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Asking for library or tool recommendations is off topic. Posting a question that shows no research effort deserves a down vote.

Comment: I have researched on this issue; how do you know that i didn't do research? It seems like it doesn't exist! I need to calculate this at real time in iPhone a dozen time per second. I will look into sympy, thanks El3Phanten.

Comment: I said your question shows no research effort. I didn't say you didn't do any. How would I know based on the information in your question?

Comment: Bryan, I don't want to use wolfram alpha, because I want to solve this even without internet connection. I just need a tool to solve an equation and returns the value of the variable.

Comment: See this SO question for [Mathematica clones}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550/best-open-source-mathematica-equivalent)

Comment: iOS does not include the Python framework, so how would you use sympy in iOS, EL3PHANTEN?

Comment: Using Python to use sympy in iOS is not feasible.

Comment: it is possible to run python in iOS. there are some port of CPython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any math library that could do this in iOS Objective C.

But I realized that coming up with the formula with the answer is easy with coding. Whenever there are many constants you can you create a new variable that includes all constants, and go on and on.

I solved the intersection of 3 spheres given those 3 equations using this method.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [this C++ library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). For those things C++ is much better. And in Objective-C you can write C-Code wherever you want.

You could also create an Objective-C wrapper class to make it more neat in your other code

Comment: Thanks so much for posting; can this do solve option? And is it easy to use in iOS?

Comment: I didn't use it myself so I can't report experiences. It's as easy on iOS as on any other platform too... Just give it a try